How do I instruct Python to use my own compiled SQLite3?
I have compiled my own version of SQLite3 amalgamation tarball from the download page and would like to include that into my Python3 script on MacOs. Is there a way to do that via import sqlite3? As in, is it possible to instruct Python to use my own version?

pysqlite3 has Building a statically-linked library option

To build pysqlite3 statically-linked against a particular version of
SQLite, you need to obtain the SQLite3 source code and copy
sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h into the source tree.
# Download the latest release of SQLite source code and build the source
# amalgamation files (sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h).
$ wget https://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/sqlite.tar.gz?r=release \
    -O sqlite.tar.gz
$ tar xzf sqlite.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite/
$ ./configure
$ make sqlite3.c

# Copy the sqlite3 amalgamation files into the root of the pysqlite3 checkout
# and run build_static + build:
$ cp sqlite/sqlite3.[ch] pysqlite3/
$ cd pysqlite3
$ python setup.py build_static build

You now have a statically-linked, completely self-contained pysqlite3.

after above instructions you should be able to do
from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)

which would reveal SQLite version used, as I do not have access to

MacOs

I am unable to test above approach, please try doing it yourself and write if it works.

I follow the process and I getting error that it's not found: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/username/Sandbox/sqlite3ttt/pysqlite3/a.py", line 1, in <module>     from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3   File "/Users/username/Sandbox/sqlite3ttt/pysqlite3/pysqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>     from pysqlite3.dbapi2 import *   File "/Users/username/Sandbox/sqlite3ttt/pysqlite3/pysqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>     from pysqlite3._sqlite3 import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite3._sqlite3'

Thank you. My second issue was due to the fact that in the current directory, there is a subdirectory named pysqlite3 which hides build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/pysqlite3.
